# DialogFragment displayed after 2 seconds delay from Fragment in android

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment, delay, dialogfragment

**Here's my XML Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/consLay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:0.75"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

**Here's my DialogFragment:**

```
public class DialogFragment_Map extends DialogFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private String mCityName;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker mMarker;
    private LatLng mLatLng;
    private FragmentDialogMapBinding fragmentDialogMapBinding;

    public DialogFragment_Map newInstance(String cityName, LatLng latLng) {
        DialogFragment_Map dialog = new DialogFragment_Map();
        dialog.mCityName = cityName;
        dialog.mLatLng = latLng;
        dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.TransparentDialog);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentDialogMapBinding = FragmentDialogMapBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        fragmentDialogMapBinding.setProgressStatus(true);
        fragmentDialogMapBinding.setCityName(mCityName);
        fragmentDialogMapBinding.btnClose.setOnClickListener(v -> dismiss());
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment smf = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapContainer, smf).commit();
        smf.getMapAsync(this);
        fragmentDialogMapBinding.executePendingBindings();
        return fragmentDialogMapBinding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(() -> {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLng, 11));
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(mLatLng);
            markerOptions.title(mCityName);
            markerOptions.icon(getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_marker);
            mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment fragment = (getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapContainer));
        FragmentTransaction ft = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (fragment != null) {
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm calling the above DialogFragment from Fragment:**

```
new DialogFragment_Map().newInstance(city.getTitle(), city.getLatLon()).
                show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

When the above line is executing from Fragment, the DialogFragment is displaying after few seconds (late than the speed of an activity open). Is there anything that is causing this delay. What can be done to open the DialogFragment instantly like a new activity open.